# Plotting Mars HiRISE images with equirectangular projection

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I'm trying to plot images taken by [HiRISE](https://www.uahirise.org), a high resolution camera taking pictures of Mars, on a map of Mars. I'm working on the image [AEB_000001_0000](https://www.uahirise.org/AEB_000001_0000), [label file](https://hirise-pds.lpl.arizona.edu/PDS/RDR/AEB/ORB_000000_000099/AEB_000001_0000/AEB_000001_0000_RED.LBL).

["Software Interface Specification for HiRISE Reduced Data Record Products"](https://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/pdf/HiRISE_RDR_SIS.pdf) has relevant equations starting on page 14. I've written a function to get the latitude and longitude of points given a sample and line. For testing, I've written a function to get latitude and longitude given a sample and line (x and y of pixels of the image), and functions for different projections. To start, I used a [Hammer projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_projection). This is what that looks like:

[image: Hammer projection of HiRISE image of part of Mars surface]

As described in the specification, this image uses an equirectangular projection. When projected, the image should be angled like this map-projected image:[image: Map-projected image of part of Mars surface]

This is what is plotted with an equirectangular projection:

[image: Equirectangular projection of HiRISE image of part of Mars suface]

It's not angled, as the map-projected image is. I'm unsure why it should be angled, because an equirectangular projection is based on straight lines (I'm not very familiar with cartography, and it's likely that I misunderstand this). Is this something wrong with my implementation, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Here's a program you can run (Python) to test this. You can switch between `calculate_coordinate_equirectangular` and `calculate_coordinate_hammer`.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# values from label file AEB_000001_0000_RED.LBL
EQUATORIAL_RADIUS = 3391.1592284034
POLAR_RADIUS = 3391.1592284034
LON_P = 180.000
LAT_P = -30.000
SCALE = 2.49
S_0 = -2563790.5
L_0 = -793892.5

# equations are described in "Software Interface Specification for HiRISE Reduced Data Record Products" https://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/pdf/HiRISE_RDR_SIS.pdf
a = POLAR_RADIUS * math.cos(math.radians(LAT_P))
b = EQUATORIAL_RADIUS * math.sin(math.radians(LAT_P))
R = (EQUATORIAL_RADIUS * POLAR_RADIUS) / math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2))

def calculate_longitude_latitude(sample, line):
    longitude = math.radians(LON_P) + (sample - S_0 - 1)*SCALE/1000/(R * math.cos(math.radians(LAT_P)))
    latitude = -(1 - L_0 + line) * SCALE / 1000 / R
    return (math.degrees(longitude), math.degrees(latitude))

def calculate_coordinate_equirectangular(longitude, latitude):
    x = R * (math.radians(updateLongitude(longitude)) - math.radians(LON_P)) * math.cos(math.radians(LAT_P))
    y = R * math.radians(latitude)
    return (x, y)

def calculate_coordinate_hammer(longitude, latitude):
    x = (2 * math.sqrt(2) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude)) * math.sin(math.radians(updateLongitude(longitude)/2))) / math.sqrt(1 + math.cos(math.radians(latitude))*math.cos(math.radians(updateLongitude(longitude)/2)))
    y = math.sqrt(2) * math.sin(math.radians(latitude)) / math.sqrt(1 + math.cos(math.radians(latitude))*math.cos(math.radians(updateLongitude(longitude)/2)))
    return (x, y)

def updateLongitude(longitude):
    return longitude if longitude <= 180 else longitude - 360

mars_image = Image.open('AEB_000001_0000.jpg')
mars_image = mars_image

x_points = []
y_points = []
colors = []
width, height = mars_image.size

for line in range(height):
    for sample in range(width):
        lon, lat = calculate_longitude_latitude(sample, line)
        x, y = calculate_coordinate_equirectangular(lon, lat)
        color = mars_image.getpixel((sample, line))
        x_points.append(x)
        y_points.append(y)
        colors.append(color)

plt.scatter(x_points, y_points, s=0.1, c=colors)
plt.show()
```